# Why GraphQL shows first item from array as all items?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

I'm trying to fetch items from GraphQL and receiving (looked at 'Network' tab):
[image]

But when I do

```
console.log(data)
```

I receive same Object as first a lot of times.
For example, not [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], but [0,0,0,0,0,0].
What's wrong?

Comment: You really need to display some code or more information, this question is not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API is returning `null` as the value for each item's `id` property. Apollo's `InMemoryCache` is normalized and uses the `id` and `__typename` of each object is stores as the key. Since the id for each item are the same, they are getting overwritten in the cache.

The easiest solution is to fix your server so it correctly returns the `id` for each item -- that will fix the unexpected caching behavior. If for some reason you don't have a unique identifier for each item, you'll need to implement your own `dataIdFromObject` function and pass it in to `InMemoryCache`'s configuration. See [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#normalization) for additional details in the docs.

Comment: Thank's! You've helped a lot